# Error after magento upgrade

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, magento-2.0, code-generation

After firing this command in CLI `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I am getting below error -:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory 
/var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.' in 
/var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...')
#4 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...')
#5 /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectMana in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 103`
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have solved this problem by just simply doing this steps.
follow steps :

1. Delete the "di" folder located in `var` directory (for `2.0` and `2.1`)
2. Run this command and go to your project root folder command:

   ```
   cd /yourmagentoroot/
   ```

   If your Magento mode is developer then you don't need to run below commands just remove `var/generation` directory(2.0 & 2.1) or `generated` folder(2.2 onwards)
3. Then run this command

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```
4. Then run this command (required in production mode only)

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
5. Finally, give file/directory permissions.(If needed)

Comment: How can i solve SUDO : https://snag.gy/hC5JDL.jpg

Comment: @zus in windows try without sudo

Comment: How to give file/directory permissions in wamp windows? @Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: @Gem I think in windows its not needed

Comment: @gem in linux if your user and php user is different then this issue might arise

Comment: For my clarity, what is mean user and PHP user is different?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala can you please answer this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322549/85990

Answer (score 31):

Giving full control (read/write/execute) to **var** and **pub** directory solved this issue for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Or, you may also try running the command using **sudo**.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Also, try clearing cache.

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
```

Comment: In some cases if you have sudo access to magento filesystem owner or webserver user(www-data/nginx). You can execute command like this: sudo -u www-data bin/magento list--

Answer (score 12):

Setup ownership again

```
CentOS: chown -R :apache .
Ubuntu: chown -R :www-data .
```

Refer this [Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/file-system-perms.html)

Comment: now i am getting this error

Comment: Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line 152
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Autoload/ClassLoaderWrapper.php on line 81
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 317
Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/magento/magento2.0/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line

Comment: @murtuza please clear your `var/generation` folder and `cache` dirs within `var` and try again.