# Getting "Command line user does not have read and write permissions on var/generation directory" when trying to access php bin/magento

Tags: permissions, ssh

Trying to get a basic grasp of `ssh` and `cli` on Magento 2.1 to "easily" install themes and extensions, but I'm dead in the water from the get go.  I have a working version of 2.1 running on a **VPS**.

Ran into this error and can't find how to address it before using the Magento Command line.

When trying to access `php bin/magento`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried sudo php bin/magento

Comment: When I do, I get the following:    "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"   I'm not sure what this means or what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Give full control (read/write/execute) to var directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var
```

Or you can run the command using sudo.

```
sudo php bin/magento {your command}
```

For more details, refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97141/23943) link.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error means that your directory which Magento trying to use has an inappropriate owner. You can check it easily using:

```
ls -la var/generation
```

from the Magento root directory. If your web-server user (usually it is `www-data` user) has no permission to write in this directory (or delete it), you should give those permissions or change an owner, like:

```
sudo chown -R www-data var/generation
```

In case you have no permissions to do that, but you have to write permissions you can simply move that directory to some other place and Magento will regenerate it during the next call to a cli.

Note: in case many users will work with those files, you can use a group and add write permissions to a group. Set write permissions for `Other`s (all users) is not a good idea.