# Command line user does not have read and write permissions on generated directory

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

> command line user does not have read and write permissions on
> generated directory. Please address this issue before using Magento command line

When I was trying to run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

And I found I get the exactly same error when I tried to run the `php bin/magento` lines, I checked the post [Error after magento upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91838/error-after-magento-upgrade/97141#97141), and have already changed the permission of generated folder, and then give bin/magento file to 744 (executable), and I used ls -l, the ownership of the folder is below to my account. I am using Magento 2.2, So there is no `di` folder under `var` folder.
So why does this error happen ?

Thanks for any advises.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check folder and files owner/group

Comment: This isnt a magento issue this is a server issue you need to make sure you have the relevant permissions and ownership setup on each of your directories. please take a look at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Answer (score 0):

More likely than an issue with *bin/magento* (even though actually there is no executable bit on any level of access) there is an issue with a generated folder. As you can read in [documentation for v2.2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html) compiled files changed their paths to /generated/*

I assume that you have properly set privileges bits for the previous version but maybe you missed setgid/uid bits and therefore user executing PHP script does not have access to this file (all is a file in Unix, also dirs).

Comment: Try to run bin/magento with root user. With root user if you didn't get problem then you need to check your normal permission with server support.