# Error after upgraded to 2.3.0

Tags: exception, magento2.3.0

Recently I had upgraded version from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 everything is working fine except frontend.It is showing below exception.Admin working perfectly.

> 1 exception(s):Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred
>   when creating object:
>   Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type
>   Error occurred when creating object:
>   Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider
>   0/var/www/magentohost/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Cms\Mod...',
>   Array)

Comment: Please refer and follow the steps. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91838/error-after-magento-upgrade

Comment: I had already tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have the issue at  __construct(.

You must pass context object `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context` $context to parent class `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    CustomHelper $helper
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
parent::__construct($context);
}
```

after this changes donot forgot to do Di compile

Comment: On which file to add this line?

Comment: The file you mentioned, Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider

Comment: I added above line inside the construct but no change same error showing again...

Comment: Hey Somebody please help me to fix this issue otherwise my client will fire me from this project..It's urgent

Comment: Finally I solved the Issue By Removing Plumrocket Extension.This extension caused the bug in Magento 2.3.0..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

This error usually means your generated sources are out of date. It doesn't seem to recognize that the $pricingHelper argument is there, which suggests it hasn't always been (extension upgrade?). Give this a try from SSH:

Change directories to your web root (the base Magento folder)
Run these commands:

php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -r var/di var/generation
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

The first one flushes Magento's cache, to make sure nothing is stuck/out of date there. The second one clears out all existing generated source files. And finally, the third generates fresh copies. When that's done, give it another try.

Comment: Finally I solved the Issue By Removing Plumrocket Extension.This extension caused the bug in Magento 2.3.0..!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the Issue By Removing Plumrocket Extension.This extension caused the bug in Magento 2.3.0..!!