# DI compile step keeps failing after upgrading from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 via composer. [Magento 2 EE]

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento-upgrade, magento2-enterprise

```
The error is the same every time I've tried, which is:
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\NodeList::item($index) : ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface must be compatible with Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\NodeListInterface::item(int $index): ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface in vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php on line 19

Comment: It seems folder path is not correct, it should be vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php? Also could you please compare the same file with default magento 2.3.5 version?

Comment: @Nits Path is proper edited my error message again, can you please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Also could you please compare the same file with default magento 2.3.5 version?

Comment: @Nits Solution:
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php (Line 45 change as follows)
public function item(int $index): ?ElementInterface